Subject-based addressing in NATS Protocol
i have been looking at source @ https://github.com/nats-io/nats.c but can't seem to locate the section which resolves wildcarded targets to subjects. could anybody help?
example:

nats pub one message to a.X.c, a.Y.c respectively.
consumer consumes from a..c <-- where in the code does a..c resolve to a.X.c and a.Y.c ?


If you subscribe to a.*.c, it will match subjects like a.X.c, a.Y.c, etc.
Refer this: https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/subjects
